# SQL Queries for Creating a rollback point and to rollback to that specific point

Tags: sql, sql-server, commit, rollback

As per my project requirement i want to perform two operation

1. Password Change
2. Unlock Account(Only unlocking account, no password change!)

I want return success only if both the transactions succeeds. Say if password change succeeds and unlock fails i cannot send success or failure. So i want to create a rollback point before password change, if both queries executes successfully i will commit the transaction. If one of the query fails i will discard the changes by rolling  back to the rollback point. I am doing this in C++ using ADO. Is there any SQL Queries,using i can create the rollback point and reverting to rollback point and commiting the transaction

I am using below commands for 
**Password change**

```
ALTER LOGIN [username] WITH PASSWORD = N'password'
```

**for Unlock account**

```
ALTER LOGIN [%s] WITH CHECK_POLICY = OFF
ALTER LOGIN [%s] WITH CHECK_POLICY = ON
```

Thanks in advance!!

Santhosh

Answer (score 1):

The nature of DDL statements is that each one constitiutes its own discrete transaction.  Think of it this way: a COMMIT is issued at the start of the DDL statement and another at the end of a successful completion of the statement.  There is no option to rollback a successful DDL statement.  [Find out more.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122.aspx)

However the [ALTER LOGIN syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) would allow you to combine the password change and unlocking statements into one:

```
ALTER LOGIN [username] WITH PASSWORD = 'password' UNLOCK ;
```

There is no single statement to unlock a password without changing the password, so for that option you need to toggle the CHECK_OPTION in the manner you describe.

Answer (score 0):

some SQL supports transactions. Put the queries within a transaction-block. If any query fails within the block, all is rolled back. This is how it looks for MySQL:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER this CHANGE that;
...
COMMIT;
```